# Webpack 5 SplitChunksPlugin then what?

Tags: webpack

I have just started to look in to the SplitChunksPlugin and it generates some new bundles for example `120.b01d2775b45c779ccb2e.bundle.js`. When I navigate to the page I can see the user_spa.bundle.js gets loaded as usual, but then the page is just a blank white page, no errors.

I have used react and lazy-loading on the routes and it generates similar bundles. But they get loaded when navigate to a new route on demand.

I thought code-splitting would work in similar way. But there must be something I'm missing here.

This is the webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "App"),
    entry: {
        user_spa: ["./Spa/user_spa.js"],
        admin_spa: ["./Spa/admin_spa.js"],
        login_spa: ["./Spa/login_spa.js"],
    },
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true
                },
            },
        },
    },
    target: ["web", "es5"],
}
```

Could some kind soul please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone come across this question and are confused as I was.
Splitchunks will create new bundles that you need to add as script-tags in your index html file. If you use HtmlWebpackPlugin you could use that to automaticlly include them.
But in my case we did not and there fore I needed to add them manually.

Here is the end result:

```
optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    idHint: 'vendors',
                },
                assets: {
                    test: /[\\/]Assets[\\/](?!Resources)/,
                    name: 'assets',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    idHint: 'assets',
                },
                components: {
                    test: /(?!Spa)[\\/]Components[\\/]/,
                    name: 'components',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                    idHint: 'components',
                },
            },
        },
    },

<script src="@Url.Script("build", "runtime.bundle.js")" nonce="@Context.GetNonce()"></script>
<script src="@Url.Script("build", "vendors.bundle.js")" nonce="@Context.GetNonce()"></script>
<script src="@Url.Script("build", "assets.bundle.js")" nonce="@Context.GetNonce()"></script>
<script src="@Url.Script("build", "components.bundle.js")" nonce="@Context.GetNonce()"></script>
<script src="@Url.Script("build", "user_app.bundle.js")" nonce="@Context.GetNonce()"></script>
```